The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {...} was not handled by any navigator error in FlatList onPress
Don't know why NAVIGATE can't find screen named 'ChatList'. See code:
NewChatScreen.js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  TextInput,
  ActivityIndicator,
  FlatList,
} from "react-native";
import { HeaderButtons, Item } from "react-navigation-header-buttons";
import CustomHeaderButton from "../components/CustomHeaderButton";
import PageContainer from "../components/PageCointainer";

import { FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import colors from "../constants/colors";
import commonStyle from "../constants/commonStyle";
import { searchUsers } from "../utils/actions/userActions";
import DataItem from "../components/DataItem";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { setStoredUsers } from "../store/userSlice";

const NewChatListScreen = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState();
  const [noResultsFound, setNoResultsFound] = useState(false);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

  const userData = useSelector((state) => state.auth.userData);

  useEffect(() => {
    props.navigation.setOptions({
      headerLeft: () => {
        return (
          <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={CustomHeaderButton}>
            <Item title="Zamknij" onPress={() => props.navigation.goBack()} />
          </HeaderButtons>
        );
      },
      headerTitle: "Nowy chat",
      headerTitleAlign: "center",
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const delaySearch = setTimeout(async () => {
      if (!searchTerm || searchTerm === "") {
        setUsers();
        setNoResultsFound(false);

        return;
      }

      setIsLoading(true);

      const usersResult = await searchUsers(searchTerm);
      delete usersResult[userData.userId];
      setUsers(usersResult);

      if (Object.keys(usersResult).length === 0) {
        setNoResultsFound(true);
      } else {
        setNoResultsFound(false);

        dispatch(setStoredUsers({ newUsers: usersResult }));
      }

      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 500);

    return () => clearTimeout(delaySearch);
  }, [searchTerm]);

  const userPressed = (userId) => {
    props.navigation.navigate("ChatList", {
      selectedUserId: userId,
    });
  };

  return (
    <PageContainer>
      <View style={styles.searchContainer}>
        <FontAwesome name="search" size={15} color={colors.lightGrey} />

        <TextInput
          placeholder="Szukaj"
          style={styles.searchBox}
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            setSearchTerm(text);
          }}
        />
      </View>

      {isLoading && (
        <View style={commonStyle.center}>
          <ActivityIndicator size={"large"} color={colors.primary} />
        </View>
      )}

      {!isLoading && !noResultsFound && users && (
        <FlatList
          data={Object.keys(users)}
          renderItem={(itemData) => {
            const userId = itemData.item;
            const userData = users[userId];

            return (
              <DataItem
                title={`${userData.firstName} ${userData.lastName}`}
                subTitle={userData.about}
                image={userData.profilePicture}
                onPress={() => userPressed(userId)}
              />
            );
          }}
        />
      )}

      {!isLoading && noResultsFound && (
        <View style={commonStyle.center}>
          <FontAwesome
            name="question"
            size={55}
            color={colors.lightGrey}
            style={styles.noResultsIcon}
          />
          <Text style={styles.noResultsText}>Nie znaleziono użytkowników</Text>
        </View>
      )}

      {!isLoading && !users && (
        <View style={commonStyle.center}>
          <FontAwesome
            name="users"
            size={55}
            color={colors.lightGrey}
            style={styles.noResultsIcon}
          />
          <Text style={styles.noResultsText}>
            Wprowadź imię by wyszukać użytkownika
          </Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </PageContainer>
  );
};

MainNavigator.js
import React from "react";

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import Ionicons from "@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons";

import ChatListScreen from "../screens/ChatListScreen";
import ChatSettingsScreen from "../screens/ChatSettingsScreen";
import SettingsScreen from "../screens/SettingsScreen";
import ChatScreen from "../screens/ChatScreen";
import NewChatScreen from "../screens/NewChatScreen";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const TabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerTitle: "",
        headerShadowVisible: false,
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="ChatList"
        component={ChatListScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: "Czaty",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <Ionicons name="chatbubble-outline" size={size} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Settings"
        component={SettingsScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: "Ustawienia",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <Ionicons name="settings-outline" size={size} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const MainNavigator = (props) => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Group>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Dom"
          component={TabNavigator}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="ChatSettings"
          component={ChatSettingsScreen}
          options={{
            gestureEnabled: true,
            headerTitle: "Ustawienia",
            headerBackTitle: "Wstecz",
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="ChatScreen"
          component={ChatScreen}
          options={{
            headerTitle: "",
            headerBackTitle: "Wstecz",
          }}
        />
      </Stack.Group>

      <Stack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: "containedModal" }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="NewChat" component={NewChatScreen} />
      </Stack.Group>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default MainNavigator;

DataItem.js
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback } from "react-native";
import ProfileImage from "./ProfileImage";
import colors from "../constants/colors";

const DataItem = (props) => {
  const { title, subTitle, image } = props;

  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={props.onPress}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ProfileImage uri={image} size={40} />
        <View style={styles.textContainer}>
          <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.title}>
            {title}
          </Text>

          <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.subTitle}>
            {subTitle}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
};

This should move me to new chat screen user I clicked. Why it can't see 'ChatList' screen? Function 'userPressed' is needed as I want to have 'userId' on this press.
EDIT: Added more code to add context.

Can you post the full navigation setup to give more context into the issue?

Where is NewChatScreen in relation to ChatList?

Added more code

NewChatListScreen and ChatList are not in the same stack to navigation.navigate both screens should be in same stack if they are is different stack they you should nested navigation navigation.navigate(yourstackname ,{screen:taregtScreenName})
